# Can't made changes on synonym using spring

Tags: spring, oracle

I created a synonym called `CLASSE_SYN` with oracle.

Using Spring, I do like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLASSE_SYN")
public class Classe implements Serializable {}
```

and I add on `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.synonyms" value="true"/>
```

But I can't made changes on that synonym from spring code source.

Have you please any idea about solving that issue ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrade your hibernate version.
Hibernate 4.3.0 supports your need.
HTH.